# how to get dy/dt in ode45 matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 relations:

```
y=y0+V*t+sin(w*t)    #relation1
dy/dt=(current/P)-(M1/P)*sin(y)+(M2/P)*sin(y+E)+U*cos(y)*sin(w*t)    #relation2
```

(M1,P,M2,E,w & U are numerical constants)
My goal is to find V(voltage) for different currents. in order to do that, I have to solve relation 2 numerically for different currents, and get dy/dt and then by using the relation between y and V which is <∂y/∂t>=V (<....> denotes a time average), I have to find V.
consider that I don`t know the value of dy/dt.
I tried this

```
current = 6e-7 : 1e-8 : 8.5e-7;
for k=1:length(current)
f = @(y, t, M1, P, M2, E) (current(k)/P)-(M1/P)*sin(y)+(M2/P)*sin(y+E)+U*cos(y)*sin(w*t);
[t{k}, y{k}] = ode45(f,tspan,y0);
end
```

this gives me y for different currents in a cell.

I found out that the following code will give me dy/dt:

```
ydot=y(:,2)   #if I use 1 instead of 2 it will give me y)
```

but Now, my problem is changed to this:
when I use this code, It will give me dy/dt only for 1 current, how can I get dy/dt for different currents?

Comment: Do you mean that dy/dV = V? You say "the relation between y and V [...] is dy/dt = V".

Comment: No, first I have to get dy/dt and by <∂y/∂t>=V (time averaged dy/dt) I will get V.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your output a vector, where the first element is the state that you are interested in (`y`), and the second element is its derivative with respect to time (`dy/dt`); so `y0 = [0;0];` or whatever your starting conditions are. Then make a separate file for your ODE, let's call it "myFcn":

```
function dydt = myFcn(~, y, M1, P, M2, E, current)      % the ~ is because we are not explicitly dependent on tspan

% Initialize the d/dt vector of our states, y
dydt = zeros(size(y));

% Update the d/dt vector of our states
dydt(1) = y(2);                                         % because (d/dt)y(1) = y(2) = dydt
dydt(2) = current/P - (M1/P)*sin(y) + (M2/P)*sin(y+E);  % your update equation
```

Now just replace your handle and `ode45` call in the above with:

```
f = @(y, M1, P, M2, E, current(k))myFunc(y, M1, P, M2, E, current(k));
[t{k}, y{k}] = ode45(f, tspan, y0);
```

Your output will then be the vector `y` that will give your "position" state `y(1)` and "velocity" state `y(2)`. These will be stored in your cell array as before.

### Edit:

Updated code to include `current(k)`, remaining consistent with OP's code.

Comment: well, I did not understand your method totally, But I have to be able to change current & get dy/dt, I didn`t find any current(k) in your solution to change my current.

Comment: @user2822314 What are you doing with your current? Do you just need to simulate the system at different constant input currents and see what happens? Or are you varying your current during a single simulation?

Comment: I need to simulate the system at different constant input currents (for example: current=0:0.136:1e6)

Comment: @user2822314 I updated the code to include `current(k)` instead of just `current`. Basically you are creating a separate function (first block of code), and then just replacing the lines in your `for` loop with the second block of code above. Also, you maybe be able to get this to run faster if you can figure out a way to pass the whole vector of currents at once and simulate for all of them at the same time. Something to think about.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to simply differentiate, you could use f2 = jacobian(f,[dt]) and matlabfunction(f2) to get back a function handle...

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn`t work for numerical answers.